# Find the the probability using a probability table?

Tags: statistics

I have the following probability table. X is the random variable.

$X=0 ,P(X)=1/27$

$X=1, P(X)=6/27$

$X=2 , P(X)=12/27$

$X=3 , X=8/27$

**Find $P(1<X\le3$)**

I put =8/27

find $P(X>2)$

I am not sure how to find this one. I would guess it is 8/27.

Comment: For $1\lt X\le 3$, that happens if $X=2$ or $X=3$. For the probability, add together the probabilities of the outcomes $2$ and $3$, we get $\frac{20}{27}$. Your guess for $\Pr(X\gt 2)$ is right, but it should not be a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem gives us a probability table, we assume those are the only possible values of our random variable $X$ for that given experiment.

For the first probability, since $X$ has to be greater than $1$ (that is it cannot be equal to $1$), and it has to be less than or equal to $3$. So the possible values of $X$ in that interval are only $2$ and $3$. So,$$\begin{align}P(1<X\leq3) &= P(X=2 \text{ or } X=3) \\ &= P(X=2) + P(X=3) \\ &=\frac{12}{27} + \frac{8}{27} . \end{align}$$

Similarly,
$$\begin{align}P(X>2) &= P(X=3) \\ &=\frac{8}{27} . \end{align}$$